# Define custom ViewGroup attributes for children

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-custom-attributes

I am looking for a way to define custom attributes for views that are used by their children. For example `layout_centerInParent` for children of `RelativeLayouts` or `layout_span` for children of `TableLayouts`.

Comment: why do you think they ar used by children and not where they are defined?

Comment: I am pretty sure there was a time when using attributes that were declared in the parent led to a lint error. I just tried it again without problems.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just in case someone else gets here hoping for a direction like I did:

The layout parameters that are defined in the children are used in the parents. For example, `layout_centerInParent` is used by the `RelativeLayout` parent to position the child according to its value of this attribute.

In a custom ViewGroup you can create an inner class that extends `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`. Then you can use XML attributes within the children and retrieve them in the custom layout using the [`View#getLayoutParams()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLayoutParams()) method.

You can look at [this question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970601/how-to-create-a-custom-layoutparams-to-be-used-on-a-custom-layout).